# Authentication in client-side Blazor web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-client-side

I've been trying to learn some `C#` and decided to try a `Blazor` app. I've been building web apps for a long time but not in the MS world. In reading the [blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) it seems that a client side blazor app cannot be secured by role, since the user could simply change any js parameters and visit pages arbitrarily. However, am I wrong to think that you can still secure the basic app built with client side blazor as far as authenticating users via `OIDC` or some other auth flow?

To put it another way, it sounds like a truly secure web app would be well advised to use the client side blazor setup, but would the client side work for an intranet scenario, where we only care about making sure users should be able to login, but aren't too concerned with what they do once they're in?

Answer (score 0):

I have a repo [here](https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth) that enables roles via Blazor WASM.
This [commit](https://github.com/BrianLParker/RoleBaseAuth/commit/033eb79a60e76747b73735c15a679149935bebcf) shows the changes I made to the template. Its important to transform the roles with the CustomUserFactory as they are in a string array.